Exponential sums over a linear subspace
I'm looking into certain type of exponential sums, which are summed over a linear subspace, and I couldn't find a good reference for that.
The (simplified) setting is the following. Let $p$ be a prime, and consider a homogeneous polynomial $f:\mathbb{Z}_p^n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$. I'm interested in sums of the form:
$$
\sum_{x\in \mathcal{S}}\omega^{f(x)}
$$
where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/p}$, and $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p^n$ is defined to be the set of solutions to the linear system of equations $\langle  y_i , x \rangle=0$ for linearly independent $y_1,...,y_k\in \mathbb{Z}_p^n$ (assume $k<n$).
Any reference related to that would be useful (even possibly easier cases, e.g. $p=2, d=2$, would be very helpful).
Thanks!

I don't know any references specific to the case of exponential sums over subspaces, but the subspace is of course a vector space, and there exist many techniques for dealing with exponential sums over vector spaces, that can be potentially applied. For $p$ large (with respect to $d$) and $f$ good (in the sense of being a generic or random polynomial) there are geometric techniques as in Katz's notes on singular exponential sums. For $f$ structured there is the method of Weyl differencing.

For arbitrary $f$ there are ideas from combinatorics about structure vs. randomness e.g. results of Green and Tao on equidistribution of polynomials over finite fields and various followups to that.

OP does not specify what they would like to know about such sums, so I will address the simplest thing that comes to mind: how can we evaluate them?
If $n=2$, then these are essentially the same thing as quadratic Gauss sums, hence, can be computed efficiently in polynomial time.  If $n>2$, then without further constraints, the sums are #P-hard to evaluate.  My favorite reference about such things is Cai, Chen, Lipton and Lu's paper "On Tractable Exponential Sums".

I might note that my observations are mainly intended for the case $k=0$, i.e., when the subspace is the whole space $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$. So maybe I'm not understanding what the OP is really looking for.
